# Как залинковать EGL в windows?

Tags: c++, opengl, rust, компоновщик, clang

Я пытаюсь написать окно на winapi подключить к нему egl на Rust и использую для этого привязки сгенерированные bindgen из хэдеров egl. Встаёт разумный вопрос как прилинковать egl и реализацию её функций ? Мне советовали прилинковать opengl32, но в итоге линковщик завершается с ошибкой такого рода: `Non-UTF-8 output: winApiTest.2fshy6bi34t7iugk.rcgu.o : error LNK2019`. Буду очень благодарен за ответ